# Limit by polar coordinates

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Hi I need some help with this limit:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{x^4y}{x^2+(x+y)^2}$$
I used polar coordinates and got that
$$
\frac{x^4y}{x^2+(x+y)^2}= \frac{r^3\cdot(\cos φ)^4  \sin φ } {1+ (\cosφ)^2+\sin(2φ)}
$$
I didn't know how to proceed from this.

Comment: Erika: Yes, you can use the squeeze theorem here.. You see that for no value of $\phi$ could we simultaneously have $\cos\phi=0$ and $\sin2\phi=-1$. Therefore your denominator is always positive, so there exists a constant $K>0$ such that the denominator $\ge K$. Hence $|f(x,y)|\le \dfrac1K r^3$, and the claim follows by squeeze.

Comment: If I got it right your denominator gets its minimum value when $\phi=\pi/2+\arctan((\sqrt5-1)/2)$ so the constant $K$ is more than a bit awkward. Of course, you won't need to find the best possible $K$ to proceed, but surely the way Nitin did the final step is to be recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(x,y) \mapsto (r cos\phi, r sin\phi)$. So , when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ it is equivalent to saying that $r\to 0$. Hence, the limit would be zero since you have $r^3$ in the numerator.

Comment: Can I use the squeeze theorem to show that it goes to zero?

Comment: Yes, you can use the squeeze theorem too. For that observe that $(1+sin(2\phi))\geq 0$  and hence, $|\frac{r^3 cos^4\phi sin\phi}{1+cos^2\phi+sin(2\phi)} | \leq |\frac{r^3 cos^4\phi sin\phi}{cos^2\phi} |  \leq |\frac{r^3 cos^2\phi sin\phi}{1} |  \leq |r^3|$.

Comment: @NitinTomar That's indeed equivalent to the way we can solve without polar coordinates in this case.

Comment: @user That's indeed the case. I just answered the question using polar coordinates which was asked at the very first place.

Comment: @NitinTomar Yes I see, my comment was mainly for the asker to emphasize that in this particular case there is not a great advantage to proceed by polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, without polar coordinates, since $(x+y)^2 \ge 0$, we have that

$$x=0 \,(y\neq 0)\implies  \frac{x^4y}{x^2+(x+y)^2}=0$$

$$x\neq 0 \implies \left|\frac{x^4y}{x^2+(x+y)^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{x^4y}{x^2}\right| =x^2|y| \to 0$$

Note that using polar coordinates, to conclude by squeeze theorem again, we need to show that

$$f(\theta)=\frac{(\cos φ)^4  \sin φ } { (\cosφ)^2+2\sin φ\cos φ +1}$$

is bounded which leads to the same previous method.

Comment: Can I use the polar coordinates and use the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Squeeze theorem suffices in this case and in my opionion it is the best way. To use polar coordinates we need to show that the function of $\theta$ is bounded.

Comment: User. What happens for $x=0$, $y\not=0$? Greetings.

Comment: @PeterSzilas It seems that for $x=0$, $y\neq 0$ the original expression is equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, could be mentioned.

Comment: @PeterSzilas It seems to me that the reached inequality $\left|\frac{x^4y}{x^2+(x+y)^2}\right|\le x^2|y|$ is always true and we don't need to consider particular cases. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, but writing $|x^4y/x^2|$ does not look so good for $x=0$.Greetings+1)

Comment: @PeterSzilas Ah ok, I think you are right! I add that info also.

Comment: Perhaps looks a bit nicer if you add a little

Comment: @PeterSzilas Yes I was giving it as a simple fact but I agree it wasn't completely correct in te previous way. Thanks

Comment: No worries:)) Stay safe!